# Raspberry Piの音源とシリアル通信の権限を一般ユーザーに開放したい

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

WebのブラウザからRaspberry Piのサーバーにアクセスした一般ユーザーに、音声とシリアル通信の権限を渡し操作を許可したいのですが・・・

試したことは

音源の権限変更

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/snd/controlC0
sudo chmod 666 /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
```

シリアル通信の権限変更

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyACM0
```

上記で権限変更でき、目的の動作を確認できるのですが、リブートするたびにファイルが書き換えられて、元の状態の権限になっていることに気が付きました。

Raspberry Pi　が初Linuxでサーバーを立てるのも初めてです。
どなたかわかりやすく教えていただけないでしょうか？

Raspberry Pi3 jessie です。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「ブラウザからアクセスした一般ユーザに」は具体的にどのような手段になりますか？例えばwebサーバを立てて何らかのプログラムを実行させる等。

Comment: Webサーバとしてphpのフォームで受けたテキストを、一旦テキストファイルに保存し、exec関数でpythonで作成したOpen JTalkのファイルでしゃべらせるというものです。シリアルはUSBにArduinoが接続されていて、同時にLEDを光らせるというものです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

一般論としては、パーミッションを変更するのではなく、ユーザーをデバイスファイルの所有グループに加えた方がよいです。

例えば`/dev/snd/controlC0`であれば

```
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  0 Jan 20 23:12 controlC0`
```

のようになっていると思いますので、audioグループはこのデバイスを読み書きできます。ですので、audioグループにユーザーを追加すればそのユーザーがデバイスを読み書きできます。

ユーザーがどのグループに属しているかは`/etc/group`で管理されています。このファイルは直接編集せず、`vigr`コマンドを使って編集してください。上の例でaudioグループであれば

audio:x:29:pi

こんな行があるはずなので、末尾にカンマ区切りでユーザー（おそらくHTTPサーバの実行ユーザーになると思います）を書き足してください。

---

ただし、サーバが外部(インターネット）に公開されている場合は直接HTTPサーバの実行ユーザーに権限を与えるのは避け、デバイスにアクセスする部分は別のユーザーの権限で実行させたほうが安全です。

Comment: ユーザーをデバイスファイルの所有グループに加えるとは　　audio:x:29:pi,new_user  のような感じでしょうか　　ユーザーの追加はやったことがないのですが、情報が多いのでできそうです。　　とりあえず試してみます。ありがとうございます。

Comment: audio:x:29:pi,new_user は無事にできたのですが、「サーバが外部(インターネット）に公開されている場合は直接HTTPサーバの実行ユーザーに権限を与えるのは避け、デバイスにアクセスする部分は別のユーザーの権限で実行させ」は、vigrコマンドで表示されたHTTPに関連していそうなwww-data:x:33:の項目にnew_userを追加するという感じでしょうか？理解不足で申し訳ありません。

Comment: 一応自己解決しました。sudo vigrでaudioとdialoutのところに「,www-data」を追記しました。www-dataがサーバ（Apache）にアクセスしてきたユーザーになるようで、このwww-dataが音源(audio)とシリアル通信(dialout)を扱えるようにグループに加えるという感じなのだと思います。ただ、別のユーザーに実行させる方法はわからなかったので、こちらのより安全性が高いと思われる方法もヒントがあれば教えていただきたいです。いずれにしてもvigrとグループの追加の仕方を教えてくださりありがとうございました。